# kendo mvc grid filterable can't hide row properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to have the id of the user as a hidden column in my kendo mvc grid. Im using the new filter row function.

when i do this:

```
  .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.UserName).Width(220);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Email).Width(220);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden(true).Filterable(false).Groupable(false).Sortable(false);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Languages).ClientTemplate("#=Languages.Name#").Filterable(false).Width(175);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Customer).ClientTemplate("#=Customer.CustomerName#").Filterable(false).Width(175);
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewDetails").Click("showDetails")).Title("Change Password"); 
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(170).Title("Edit/Delete");
    })
```

it looks like this:

[image]

And if i comment out the hidden id column it looks like i want it to look.

[image]

How can i hide the column properly?

Comment: sinple use .Hidden() instead of all those additional properties

Comment: why i have all those is because ive tried them all but they don't work properly in the new filter row grid. Im starting to believe it is something that telerik needs to do some work on.